# Does Google Adsense increment the impression count for the same ad on multiple pages for the same user?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Suppose a visitor on my website visits 3 pages and the SAME ad appears more than once. Will that be counted as just one ad impression or three?

Answer (score 1):

That would be three impressions.

But the question may not matter, as the majority of Adsense impressions are CPC not CPM. If it's the former, (which it probably is) the number of times the ad appears will have no bearing on your earnings anyway.